# JSON and changing datasets

Tags: json, d3.js

I am fairly new to JSON and I want to create a choropleth example as so. http://gabrielflor.it/a-half-decade-of-rising-poverty Whenever the years are clicked it just goes to a different portion of the JSON (I'm assuming). Is this how functionality like this is usually done to avoid redrawing the whole map again and calling another JSON.js file? If so these .JSON files can get quite large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a JSON is only a way to store values you need for each year. When you switch to another year the JS parse the JSON for the giving year and update the choropleth. For the example you have provided, here is the JSON used:

http://gabrielflor.it/static/data/saipe.json

This is a good way since you only have one JSON with every year you need and you load it only once. **However since d3 needs datas this way I think you should add another JSON if you want to provide additional data** like in gabrielflor example:

http://gabrielflor.it/static/js/d3.poverty-by-county.js?v=121107

He loads JSON like this with d3:

`d3.json('../static/data/states.json', function (json) {
 states = json;
});`

or

`d3.json('../static/data/saipehighlights.json', function (json) {
    saipehighlights = json;
});`

Comment: What if I had different types of data to load in it would have to reside in a different JSON file I would assume?

Comment: If think you would have to do it in another JSON since d3 might needs the JSON file this way to parse the Choropleth. gabrielflor wrote his own code you can find in d3.poverty-by-country you can find here http://gabrielflor.it/static/js/d3.poverty-by-county.js?v=121107 for example he used `d3.json('../static/data/states.json', function (json) {

 states = json;
});` to load additional datas.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the network traffic for the example page you gave (ex. by using Chrome Developer Tools).
The file with the poverty data is quite large, but the mapping data file is even larger. You'll notice, that it takes longer for the website to load, but afterwords it runs very smoothly in the client without making any server calls.

The site is just about browsing information and nice design - for that purpose I think a longer load time is quite acceptable if the user experience after is smoother(i.e. user doesn't have to wait for year data to load).